# How can I create table in sqlite for 1:1 and 1:M relationships?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to create table for the following relationship.

One category should have one budget amount.
One category can have one ore more expenses.

[Image of ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07j9I.png)

Comment: Try to look at this https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: Okey,I Understood,but if I need to insert values to the Category and Budget table,How can I insert them?Do I need to relate then when Adding values also? I'm new to android,sry for the silly questions